# yum install Libreoffice Writer without Java

Tags: yum, centos-6, libreoffice-writer

Is it possible for me to yum install LibreOffice Writer without Java also being installed?

I don't want to install the full libreoffice package because it prompts me to update my java and tomcat which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm using CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full libreoffice installation without Java is not possible.
LibreOffice Base uses a HSQLDB with is written in Java (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSQLDB).

You can run most of the products without Java by going to Tools->Options>-LibreOffice->Java and uncheck "Use Java virtual machine"

If the Package in the CentOS-repos requires Java you can try installing the rpm directly provided by libreoffice.org or install the rpm in the centos-repo with

```
rpm --nodeps
```

Either way, make a backup first.